# Why do getTimezoneOffset() and toLocaleString() in Chrome, Safari and Firefox assume that Singapore is on timezone GMT+7.30?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, timezone

Just some background: I'm on OS X 10.9.5, my timezone is set to Singapore Standard Time (GMT+8 - we don't have daylight saving time here, I believe we never had it in the past as well, as Singapore is right next to the equator so there is virtually no seasonal difference in day light).

When I try out the below javascript on Firefox console, this is what I get:

```
> new Date(0).toLocaleString()
< "01/01/1970 7:30:00 am"
> new Date(0).getTimezoneOffset()
< -450
```

It seems that Firefox mistakes my timezone for GMT+7.30.

When I try the same thing in Safari and Chrome console, this is what I get (for both):

```
> new Date(0).toLocaleString()
< "1 January, 1970 7:30:00 am GMT+7:30"
> new Date(0).getTimezoneOffset()
< -480
```

Again, it seems that `toLocaleString()` in Safari and Chrome mistake the timezone for GMT+7.30; however `getTimezoneOffset()` gets it right.

Are these behaviours by designed in Firefox, Safari and Chrome respectively (ie. there is a reason behind them), or are they just bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is constructed with `0` so yields a date in `1970` and [historically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time):

> *Singapore Standard Time* 
>   Time offset from GMT: **UTC+07:30** 
>   Period in use: 12 September 1945 - 31 December 1981

So the string representation is correct.

As for the `getTimezoneOffset` discrepancy I would say Firefox uses the correct behaviour; see (Chrome) [Issue 3547:    timezone offset is incorrect for the past/future date for a timezone whose offset has changed over time (e.g. Europe/Moscow, America/Indiana)](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3547)